# doble etiqueta body en angular 7

Tags: css, angular7

tengo  un problema, ya que el angular me está generando doble etiqueta  por tanto al estar contenido un body dentro de otro la pantalla no se ve completa, a alguien le ha pasado?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Doble body]

Comment: Hola, aparte de las imágenes que muestran el resultado no deseado, ¿podrías incluir código (por favor que no sean imágenes) de los componentes que estás usando? Ya que sin saber cuál es la estructura o lo que estás haciendo es difícil saber dónde tienes el error. Te invito a leer [mcve]. Saludos